Geometry node proximity to generate action
In abstract, I want object A to get closer to object B, so something happens in object B (for example color change, or whatever). But I want this state to remain. The problem that I have is that when object A continue it's movement and it get away from object B, then object B go back to the initial state.
I have tried with simulation nodes, with the geometry proximity node, and I don't find the proper solution. I found a solution, that is that object A creates a hidden geometry that stays there, so the state of object B don't go batk,1 but it creates a lot of geometry and it's very heavy. I'm sure that there is a better solution, but I can't find it.
I have the file for the attached video, but I don't know how to upload it, sorry.
Update, here is the example file


[]

Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

What about a Named Attribute to store the Scale ? Initialize it with 0, then inside the Simulation Zone, update it with the maximum between the previous frame value and the actual output of the Color Ramp node. Once at 1, it will keep this value, even with the sphere away.

Hi StefLancien, thank you! I'll give it a try! If it works, I'll be back

Hi, I tried what you propose, but probably I'm missing something or I don't know how to implement it. I have uploaded the file. Thank you in advance!

Here is an example how you can store the new scale as maximum between previous and current scale and use it for scaling the elements:




Side note: If the "new scale" field is not used outside of the GN modifier, this field can be directly initialized then recycled between the Simulation Zone output and input as a "bake item", instead of using a Store Named Attribute node. See https://i.sstatic.net/CUvJUTbr.png

@StefLAncien Yes, correct. I started off differently where I used the attribute outside the simulation and then did not spend much time on making it more efficient.

Gordon, this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so so much! This solution is really useful, since it can be applied for example for color changes, or similar stuff. Again, thank you so much!
